# How to find which page something starts on in a numbered pagination of sorted results?

Tags: mysql, sql

`/users/1` is a 1st page of paginated results. It runs a query:

```
SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY surname, id LIMIT 0, 100;
```

`/users/2` adjusts the generated SQL. `LIMIT 100, 100` shows 2nd page of paginated results etc.

I want to implement A-Z links to these same paginated results, when they are ordered by surname; year based links when ordered by date; number based links when ordered by an integer field. You get the point.

e.g.: URL `/users/A` will redirect to `/users/1`, but how do I figure out efficiently which page should `/users/B` redirect to.

I know `/users/B` could just run a "filter" query to pull out users with surname starting B a display that on the page. However I want to avoid creating another page, hence I want a redirect.

I could also iterate over the results of `SELECT surname FROM users ORDER BY surname` counting where the B and other letters start and divide starting position by results per page (100), but that's inefficient. I think this needs some clever SQL. I use MySQL.

Similar question that uses Postgres:
[Pagination: Find out which page an item is on (given primary key & sorting order)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6253104/pagination-find-out-which-page-an-item-is-on-given-primary-key-sorting-order)

Comment: Be careful, your first SQL is incrementing result by 100. First should be `LIMIT 0, 100`, second `LIMIT 100, 100`, third `LIMIT 200, 100`.

Comment: Thank you, I corrected the offset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `select count(*) from users where surname<'Current'` to get current position.

Comment: Concise and works really well. Here you can see the solution in action http://medicinedict.com/amp/amp/

Answer (score 3):

How about something like this:

```
select Page
from (
    select substring(Surname, 1, 1) as SurnameFirstLetter, min(page) as Page
    from (
        select Surname, ceiling((@row := @row + 1) / 100) as page
        from users, (select @row := 0) r
        order by Surname
    ) t
    group by substring(Surname, 1, 1)
) t
where SurnameFirstLetter = 'B'
```